# installation failed - cannot execute binary file

Tags: software-installation, debian

I am installing a program and as instruction I need to type execute a .exe file. When doing this as instructions say i get:

```
cannot execute binary file: wrong format
```

The architecture of my system is i686 and the program is 64 bits version. I have Debian system. I wrote the post here because of the tag.

Any idea?

Comment: .exe is a windows pprogram

Comment: What program is this?

Comment: mopac @George. No it is not a windows program. I will check if it is .exe again.

Comment: Please provide a link to it :-)

Comment: @George how can I know if the linux version installed is 64 or 32 bits?

Comment: @George http://openmopac.net/Download_MOPAC_Executable_Step2.html

Comment: run `uname -m` in a terminal

Comment: @George it returns: `Linux huayra 3.16.0-4-586 #1 Debian 3.16.43-2+deb8u5 (2017-09-19) i686 GNU/Linux` (huayra is a debian based version). Does it tell something about the bits?

Comment: @George damn. Should I reinstall linux?

Comment: @George good. Should I remove the question? Or maybe you want to answer it.

Comment: Ok dropped an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several things to note with your situation:

1. You downloaded the wrong file for that program or you picked the `64 bit` version when your system is `32 bit`
2. Your system is `32bit` so you need the `32bit` version of that software.

Based on our conversation, a re-install of Ubuntu 64bit would be in order if you have nothing to lose, else backup your old system and then re-install. Since `32bit` systems aren't the norm these days.

To check the architecture of your run `uname -m` from a terminal:

`x86_64`: 64 bit

`i686`: 32 bit

Comment: Some extra confidence that this is not a windows program and likely some seed for more ideas could come from running "file ....exe".